# node socket io timer implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I'm creating a drawing/guess game in node & socket.
Simply said:
I have a class **Room**, **Game** (which extends Room) and a class **Round** (10 per game).
Each round a user is assigned as the drawer, the guessers have *45 seconds* to guess the word.

Upon the first guess if the timer is higher than 20 seconds, the timer is ***reduced*** to 20 seconds.

I'm not certainly sure but this is how I started:

**class Round:**

```
function Round(id, game){
  var ROUNDTIME = 45,
      timer = new Date();
  this.id = id;
  this.game = game;
  this.endTime = timer.setSeconds(timer.getSeconds() + ROUNDTIME);
  ...
}
```

**class Game:**

```
function Game(){
  this.MAX_ROUNDS = 10;
  this.rounds = [];
  this.currentRound = null;
  ...
}

Game.prototype.start = function(){
  this.nextRound;
}

Game.prototype.nextRound = function(){
  if(this.rounds.length <= this.MAX_ROUNDS){
    this.currentRound = new Round(this.rounds.length + 1, this);
    ...
  } else {
    this.endGame();
  }
}

Game.prototype.endGame = function(){
  ...
}
```

Afterwards I have a Round function which checks for the answer each time an answer/message is submitted. Upon first answer I reduce the endTime till 20 seconds left.

So have 2 questions:

1. Is this a correct/good practive approach?
2. How should I implement it further into the application itself? (setInterval of 1 second with emit? or Simply emit when the endDate is reached? or another way?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like

```
function Round(id, game,loseCallbackFn){
var ROUNDTIME = 45, startTime = new Date();
this.id = id;
this.game = game;
this.endTime = startTime.getTime()+45*1000;
this.timerId = setTimeout(loseCallbackFn,45*1000);
...
}
...
Round.onWrongGuess(){
    if((this.endTime-(new Date()).getTime())>20*1000) {// he has more than 20s left
        clearTimeout(this.timerId);
        this.timerId = setTimeout(loseCallbackFn,20*1000);
        ...
    }else{
        loseCallbackFn();
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Hey mido22, thanks for replying. Where does the callback come from? As I give the game class (which contains a nextRound function) as the parameter. I updated my question with the Game class.

Comment: in that case, you can drop the callback from parameters, and pass```game.endGame ``` in callback function's place,( or any other function you declared in Game object to handle failure scenario)

Comment: How about using a callback on a function which emits the update of the countdown script(in combination with the game.endRound())? Or isn't this a good pratice (inserting socket functionality into a class)?

Comment: @goowik I believe it would be better leave  socket  code  out,  one  way to do that is,  make  a closure on  socket code  side  and  set  to a variable in  your game  object.